# PHP code completes successfully when user input is entered incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with this segment of code in an application I'm writing:

```
<?php

session_start();

include('api/dbconnect.php');

$msg = "";

if(isset($_POST['register-submit'])) {
// Now we check if the data was submitted, isset() function will check if the data exists.
    if (!isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
        $msg = 'Please complete the registration form';
    }
// Make sure the submitted registration values are not empty.
    if (empty($_POST['first_name']) || 
        empty($_POST['last_name'])  || 
            /* empty($_POST['email']) || */ 
        empty($_POST['username']) || 
        empty($_POST['password'])) {
        
        // One or more values are empty.
        $msg = 'All fields are required for the form to be submitted';
    }

    /*if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        die ('The email address provided is invalid');
    }*/

    if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', $_POST['username']) == 0) {
        $msg = 'The username provided is invalid';
    }

    if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 5) {
        $msg = 'Password must be between 5 and 20 characters';
    }

    if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_pwd']) {
        $msg = 'The two password provided do not match.';
    }

    // We need to check if the account with that username exists.
    if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = ?')) {
        // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['username']);
        $stmt->execute();
        // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // Username already exists
            $msg = 'Another account with this username already exists';
        } else {
            // Username doesn’t exist, insert new account
            if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) {
                // We do not want to expose passwords in our database, so hash the password and use password_verify when a user logs in.
                $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['first_name']);
                $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['last_name']);
                $stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST['username']);
                $stmt->bindParam(5, $password);
                $stmt->execute();
                header('Location: users.php');
            } else {
                // Something is wrong with the SQL statement. Check to make sure the users table exists with all three fields.
                $msg = 'There was a problem creating this account. Contact your Network Administrator.';
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else {
        // Something is wrong with the SQL statement. Check to make sure the users table exists with all 3 fields.
        $msg = 'There was a problem creating this account. Contact your network administrator.';
    }
    //$con->close();
}

?>
```

This code is supposed to create a new user and add them into a MySQL table. The code is working, but the code does not produce an error even if it's on purpose. For example, if I enter two different passwords, then the code thinks that there isn't a problem, so it completes the registration successfully. Everywhere there is a `$msg` variable, the code needs to stop and reload the page to show the error inside the HTML form so that the user can correct it, but it isn't working.

What am I not seeing in the code?

Here is the HTML form that the code belongs to:

```
<form class="user" method="post" action="user_new.php">
  <div class="custom-control small">
    <strong class="text-danger"><?php echo $msg; ?></strong>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
      <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address (optional)" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
      <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="confirm_pwd" name="confirm_pwd" placeholder="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="register-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" style="background-color: #a40000; border-color: #a40000;">Create User Account</button>
  <hr>
  <a href="users.php" class="btn btn-warning btn-user btn-block" style="background-color: #2658a8; border-color: #2658a8;">Return to Users</a>
</form>
```

Comment: After you set `$msg` to something `return` instead of letting the code continue. As written the values you have placed in `$msg` aren't being used for anything.

Comment: Do I need ```return``` somewhere?

Comment: In addition to Dave's comment: `$msg` is just a variable declaration. You need to echo it and then make it stop there to no longer continue. This can be achieved in many ways though.

Comment: You're also mixing different mysql apis; you can't do that. `num_rows` is mysqli_, not PDO.

Comment: When the username does not exist, you go on with the INSERT without checking anything.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things with your code that need attention to.

*Side note about point #1, see "Additional notes" below.*

1. `$msg` < you didn't do anything with that variable. They are only variable declarations. You can echo that on the page you want to echo that variable and add `exit;` after it in order to make it stop executing.
2. `num_rows` is a mysqli_ function. You can't mix that with PDO. You could use `rowCount()` or `fetchColumn()` with an `if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){...}` .

   or with `fetchColumn()`:

   ```
    $if_row = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    if ($if_row > 0) {
        $msg = "A record exists.";
    }
   ```
3. Add an `exit;` after each header. Otherwise, your code might want to continue to go further.

   Note: Since you're using a header to redirect, make sure that you're not outputting before header, otherwise it will fail.

Additional notes:

Using `if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare....){...}` probably isn't a good idea since that could fail silently and prematurely. I would "not" make it a conditional statement and then check if a row exists and handle the errors from there.

Plus, your `<?php echo $msg; ?>` inside your form could throw an undefined variable message. You could use a [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for it or a standard `if/else`.

E.g.:

```
<?php if(!empty($msg)) { echo $msg; } ?>
```

Comment: I have to point out that `rowCount` is rarely a good option. You usually don't need to know the number of returned records. In this case OP definitely doesn't need it.

Comment: @Dharman Ok thanks. I added another option to it. I agree there are more than one method to use to check if a record exists in PDO.

Comment: I don't understand how it's not being called. The last two ```$msg``` statements appear when I create a new account in my code. ```$msg``` is being called in the HTML form upon reload with an ```echo``` statement.

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle I made quite a few edits since my original post. Please reload it.

Comment: There is only one header in the PHP code and I have added the ```exit()``` to that. I still don't understand about ```$msg```. It starts in the PHP as a blank variable. Then, if an error happens, the ```$msg``` is rewritten to show the message. After that, the page needs to be refreshed and the error message shown. That is happening on the last two ```$msg``` in the PHP code.

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle If you don't want the page to reload to show a (new) message, you will need JS/Ajax/JQuery for that, given if that is what the issue is now. I am not the guy for this. I usually Google stuff and find it here on Stack.

Comment: I do want the page to reload, but I need the correct errors to appear if necessary. My login script is working and doing what I need it to do, but it is not this complicated... I could show you the login script so I can compare the two.

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle I understand. What I posted should have done/fixed that. Maybe something is wrong elsewhere. Are you using this inside the same file or 2 different files? It doesn't really matter but there could be a cache issue and is hard to say. All I changed was the `$msg` to `$if_exist` in the  "if row exists". I'll edit that now. Edit: I edited to be `$msg`.

Comment: The login code is entirely different. If I can share that code with you so you can take a look, maybe we can better determine what is wrong... The code shown in the OP is only used in this file. HTML and PHP are in the same file for error messages. Login in the same way, but the PHP is different

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle It's ok. I doubt that those 2 are related. What the other answer posted is another way of doing this. Their `if (empty($msg)` is a good way to check that if there are no more error messages, then query. I don't know how else I can help.  If something else comes to mind, I will notify you and if I made an additional edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208216/discussion-between-funk-forty-niner-and-jeremy-myrtle).

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting a variable `$msg` when a validation error occurs. This is not stopping your code from attempting to execute the database actions. Perhaps if your containing `if` statement checked if `$msg` was empty before running the database actions.

`if (empty($msg) && $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = ?')) {`

Comment: $```$msg``` is already empty before the ```if``` statement. That's what ```$msg = "";``` is for.

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle the `if` that contains the database actions, as shown above.

Comment: I get this error returned: ```Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$num_rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\cabgop\user_new.php on line 43```

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle sounds like you did something different than what I posted above.

Comment: @dqhendricks No, it's not different. Look at their code again and [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60328223/php-code-completes-successfully-when-user-input-is-entered-incorrectly#comment106716707_60328223) about it.

Comment: sounds like there are multiple problems with the code.

Comment: @Dlk Heh, no, I wouldn't do that :)

Comment: I made this change, and the last two error messages appear when something happens. But that's not what I want to happen. I need the error message that is associated with the problem appear. So, if I enter two different passwords, then the error message that says ```The two password provided do not match``` needs to appear.

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle then perhaps you should echo the $msg somewhere?